# Detecting TCP connected or not with Golang http.client?

Tags: go, http, tcp

I want to make a connection about payment to certain 3rd party API, but the problem is when its gets timeout, sometimes the request is already send to them and processed while in my system is failed because that timeout.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to detect at least its TCP/dial is connected or not, here's my code:

```
client := &http.Client {
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Dial: (&net.Dialer{
                    Timeout:   10 * time.Second,
                    KeepAlive: 10 * time.Second,
            }).Dial,
            TLSHandshakeTimeout:   10 * time.Second,
            ResponseHeaderTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        },
    }

    //url_string := "http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=25000"
    url_string := "http://192.168.7.154:8000/"
    method := "GET"

    parameters := url.Values{
        "username" : {"TEST"},
    }

    payload := strings.NewReader(parameters.Encode())
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url_string, payload)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("UNKNOWN ERROR")
        return
    }
    
    start_time := lib_time.MicroTime()
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    process_time := lib_time.MicroTime() - start_time
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v\t%v\n",err.Error(),process_time)
        return
    }
```

the problem with this script, its only shows "Get "http://192.168.7.154:8000/": net/http: timeout awaiting response headers" whatever error type of connection (TCP not connected, or TCP connected but response timeout. the context of this thread is to detect where exaclty disconnection occurs, is TCP connected but timeout waiting response? or is TCP timout because waiting to connect?

so its like this
client establish connection -> client send request -> server gets request and process -> client failed to get the response. so my goals detect connection established or not, if established i can make sure the transaction is already received to server

Comment: If you got an error, it was before any response, that’s all you can know. There’s no way to know what bytes the server received without a response from the server.

Comment: What Jim said. Pretty much all payment providers offer a way to submit transactions multiple times without causing repeat payments to happen (typically by sending some sort of unique identifier), precisely so you can safely retry if there is an error. Consult the documentation for the API in question.

Comment: its also not about payment, but also certain service too. certain local provider doesnt care about error in client side and stills validates the transaction. also im not talking about getting bytes of server. in fact i can detect tcp connect in php curl by validating "connect_time" returned from curl_getinfo()

Comment: Whether you confirm the initial tcp connection or not makes no difference in the scope of an http request. You cannot know what data made it to to server without a response from the server. You could have a valid connection, send the entire request and have nothing reach the server, only to timeout because the route was broken.

Comment: no im not talking about data, im talking about connection is established or not even before sending the data

Comment: but you literally start out talking about "data" by describing the situation as _"sometimes the request is already send to them and processed "_, and we're trying to tell you that you cannot detect this from the local TCP connection status, and trying to do so is incorrect. If you want to get a timeout error from the dialer first, make sure it returns an error before the request timeout, which is easily done by using a value slightly lower than `ResponseHeaderTimeout`, but don't make any assumption about what that means.

Comment: let me rephrase you without TLDR.

how do i get TCP connect time?

Comment: You get detailed tracing info from the [`net/http/httptrace`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptrace) package